# Excel formula only using first value in column on another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In B2 I have text to search within, in C2 I have this formula to search for words on a worksheet called "keywords" to match against.

```
{=
IF(B2="","",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!$B$2:$B$5,B2)),"Fruit",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!$C$2:$C$5,B2)),"Nature",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!$D$2:$D$5,B2)),"Vehicle",
"no match"))))
```

The formula is only using the first keyword in B2, C2, D2 on the keywords worksheet, and not through B5, C5, D5. What is the correct formula?

I understand the result will be the last satisfied statement if more than one match is found. Please help!

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPl56.png)

[keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfeuP.png)

Comment: file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rspwnetpgttko2/keywords_lookup_test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Do you mean to start the range at B3?? Of course B2 will match with B2.

Comment: Hlookup? Is that the function you are looking for?

Comment: Matt, range starts from B2 to B5 on keywords worksheet.

Comment: Andreas, how do I use hlookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non CSE array use sumproduct:

```
=
IF(B2="","",
IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!B$2:B$5,$B2))*1)>0,"Fruit",
IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!C$2:C$5,$B2))*1)>0,"Nature",
IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!D$2:D$5,$B2))*1)>0,"Vehicle",
"no match"))))
```

---

For a slightly shorter formula that uses the title row on the keywords sheet as the return value, so no need to hard code the values.  Use this:

```
=INDEX(keywords!$B$1:$D$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(keywords!$B$2:$D$5)-COLUMN(keywords!$B$2)+1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!$B$2:$D$5,B2))),1))
```

The ranges can be expanded to allow for more rows or columns in the future, without the need of adding more IF statements.

[image]

Comment: Scott, that's handy so not having to shift/Control/Enter

Comment: @ElGavino if you liked that, see my edit.  I added a second formula that looks at the whole range at once and returns the title row instead of a hard coded word.

Comment: thanks for the shorter version, though when changed the range on the keyword to only include C and D I get an #NUM! error using this
    =INDEX(keywords!$C$1:$D$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(keywords!$C$2:$D$6)-COLUMN(keywords!$C$2)+1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords!$C$2:$D$6,B3))),1))

Comment: The error on the file was due to a `0` in place of the last `1` of the formula for cell D5.  The #NUM errors is E are because there are no matches found in column D. @ElGavino

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{ =
IF(B2="","",
IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(keywords!$B$2:$B$5,B2),0))>0,"Fruit",
IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(keywords!$C$2:$C$5,B2),0))>0,"Nature",
IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(keywords!$D$2:$D$5,B2),0))>0,"Vehicle",
"no match")))) }
```

Comment: Tim, that works! Thank you! Works better than I expected as it returns the first match from the first keyword column, and not the last satisfied statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the search within your formula is looking a for a single value to search for within a specified text string therefore when you select the range `$B$2:$B$5` it selects the value in the first cell of the range of cells.

Rather then using the `SEARCH` function use `MATCH` function with a Match Type of `0` for and exact match. NOTE: this does not need to be an array formula. 
Example:

`=IF(B2="","",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,keywords!$B$2:$B$5,0)),"Fruit",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,keywords!$C$2:$C$5,0)),"Nature",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,keywords!$D$2:$D$5,0)),"Vehicle","no match"))))`

Also your statement "I understand the result will be the last satisfied statement if more than one match is found. Please help!" you may have meant the first satisfied not the last; which would be correct.

Comment: Thanks for this version, though not useful when I have more than one word in the term column.